# Why where clause doesn't affect of the query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

Here is my code:

```
$tracking_codes_obj = new TrackingCode;
$tracking_code = 140;

if ( !is_null($tracking_code) )
    $tracking_codes_obj->where('tracking_code', $tracking_code);

$tracking_codes = $tracking_codes_obj->orderBy('expired')->orderBy('id')->paginate(10);
```

As you can see `$tracking_code` is not null, so that condition is `true` and that `where` clause should be applied. But still the result is the same as when I completely remove that condition.

Why and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

The correct syntax is:

```
$tracking_codes_obj = $tracking_codes_obj->where('tracking_code', $tracking_code);
```

Comment: Also one PHP question, when exactly should I initialize an object into a variable and when shouldn't? For example in a database connection, no need to initialize anything and everything will be applied by using `->`. i.e `$db_con = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password); $db_con->exec("set names utf8");`

Answer (score 1):

you need to replace if condition like this :

```
if ($tracking_code != null)
```

Instead of

```
if ( !is_null($tracking_code) )
```

and code will be like this

```
$tracking_codes_obj = new TrackingCode;
$tracking_code = 140;

if ($tracking_code != null)
{
    $tracking_codes_obj = $tracking_codes_obj->where('tracking_code', $tracking_code);
}

$tracking_codes = $tracking_codes_obj->orderBy('expired')->orderBy('id')->paginate(10);
```

Comment: I'm not sure why did you say I shouldn't have used `is_null()` function, but anyway your code would work as well because of initializing the object. Thank you